# Is it possible to convert an interface with overloaded methods to promise version?

Tags: typescript

```js
type A = {
  a(a: string): string;
  a(a: number, b: boolean): number;
};

type Promisified<T> = ???

type B = Promisified<A>;
```

Where B expected to like:

```js
type B = {
  a(a: string): Promise<string>;
  a(a: number, b: boolean): Promise<number>;
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998823/266726) post. But only the last overloaded method remained.

Answer (score 0):

With the great help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538756/3388225).
That's the best I could come up with:

```ts
type Promisified<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: PromisifyOverloads<T[K]>
}

type PromisifyOverloads<T> =
  T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1;
    (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3;
    (...args: infer A4): infer R4
  } ? { 
    (...args: A1): Promise<R1>;
    (...args: A2): Promise<R2>;
    (...args: A3): Promise<R3>;
    (...args: A4): Promise<R4>
  } : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1;
    (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3
  } ? {
    (...args: A1): Promise<R1>,
    (...args: A2): Promise<R2>,
    (...args: A3): Promise<R3>
  } : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1;
    (...args: infer A2): infer R2
  } ? {
    (...args: A1): Promise<R1>;
    (...args: A2): Promise<R2>
  } : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1
  } ? {
    (...args: A1): Promise<R1>
   } : T
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weePVw)

Also refer to that answer for better explanation and existing limitations and edge cases.

Comment: In OP example, T[K] is not an object containing functions, but a function. I think the Promisify can be greatly simplified :
type Promisified<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => Promise<R> : T[K]
}